# How to remove MySQL completely with config and library files?

Tags: mysql, debian

So far I've tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

But whenever I try to locate MySQL using the following command, I get a list of files related to MySQL:

```
shell>> locate mysql
```

Output:

```
/etc/mysql
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql
/etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld
/etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld-akonadi
/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld
/etc/bash_completion.d/mysqladmin
/etc/init/mysql.conf
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.paranoid/mysql-server-5_5
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/mysql-server-5_5
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.workstation/mysql-server-5_5
/etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server
/etc/mysql/conf.d
/etc/mysql/debian-start
/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf
/home/pkr/.mysql_history
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/piston-helper/rec.ubuntu.com,api,1.0,recommend_app,libqt4-sql-mysql,,349051c3a57da571aa832adb39177aff
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/piston-helper/rec.ubuntu.com,api,1.0,recommend_app,mysql-client,,cbf77a486cdc80547317981a33144427
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/piston-helper/rec.ubuntu.com,api,1.0,recommend_app,mysql-client,,de8220dee4d957a9502caa79e8d2fdda
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,any,any,any,libqt4-sql-mysql,page,1,helpful,,17fb2e657321dc51526ee8fe9928da30
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,any,any,any,mysql-client,page,1,helpful,,a4c1b6e8200f36ab5745c6f81f14da0a
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,ubuntu,oneiric,any,libqt4-sql-mysql,page,1,helpful,,c54295fb82b8183350cd34f22c3547ef
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,ubuntu,oneiric,any,mysql-client,page,1,helpful,,fcf201c1abff3f774af89173a84de2cc
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,ubuntu,precise,any,libqt4-sql-mysql,page,1,helpful,,0cd86648584efeccfb16119012f89540
/home/pkr/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,ubuntu,precise,any,mysql-client,page,1,helpful,,eb84724e9da7851ff8862a227d8bac59
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql.err
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql.err.old
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/columns_priv.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/columns_priv.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/columns_priv.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/db.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/db.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/db.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/event.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/event.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/event.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/func.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/func.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/func.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/general_log.CSM
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/general_log.CSV
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/general_log.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_category.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_category.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_category.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_keyword.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_keyword.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_keyword.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_relation.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_relation.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_relation.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_topic.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_topic.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/help_topic.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/host.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/host.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/host.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/ndb_binlog_index.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/ndb_binlog_index.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/ndb_binlog_index.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/plugin.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/plugin.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/plugin.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/proc.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/proc.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/proc.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/procs_priv.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/procs_priv.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/procs_priv.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/proxies_priv.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/proxies_priv.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/proxies_priv.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/servers.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/servers.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/servers.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/slow_log.CSM
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/slow_log.CSV
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/slow_log.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/tables_priv.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/tables_priv.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/tables_priv.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_leap_second.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_leap_second.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_leap_second.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_name.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_name.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_name.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_transition.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_transition.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_transition.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_transition_type.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_transition_type.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/time_zone_transition_type.frm
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/user.MYD
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/user.MYI
/home/pkr/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/mysql/user.frm
/usr/bin/mysql
/usr/bin/mysql_install_db
/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade
/usr/bin/mysqlcheck
/usr/sbin/mysqld
/usr/share/mysql
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/gmysqlcc:gmysqlcc.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/mysql-client.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/mysql-navigator:mysql-navigator.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/mysql-server.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/gmysqlcc-32.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/mysql-navigator.png
/usr/share/doc/mysql-client-core-5.5
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-core-5.5
/usr/share/kde4/apps/katepart/syntax/sql-mysql.xml
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_install_db.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_upgrade.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlcheck.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/mysqld.8.gz
/var/cache/apt/archives/akonadi-backend-mysql_1.7.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient-dev_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient18_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libqt4-sql-mysql_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-common_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server_5.5.22-0ubuntu1_all.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-client-core-5.5.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-client-core-5.5.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.5.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.5.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-core-5.5.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-core-5.5.md5sums
/var/log/mysql
/var/log/mysql.err
/var/log/mysql.log
/var/log/mysql.log.1.gz
/var/log/mysql.log.2.gz
/var/log/mysql.log.3.gz
/var/log/mysql.log.4.gz
/var/log/mysql.log.5.gz
/var/log/mysql.log.6.gz
/var/log/mysql.log.7.gz
/var/log/upstart/mysql.log.1.gz
/var/log/upstart/mysql.log.2.gz
/var/log/upstart/mysql.log.3.gz
/var/log/upstart/mysql.log.4.gz
/var/log/upstart/mysql.log.5.gz
/var/log/upstart/mysql.log.6.gz
/var/log/upstart/mysql.log.7.gz
```

What should I do now?

I am trying to find out if there is any way I can remove all MySQL related files and then re-install MySQL.

I need it for Qt connectivity.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

With the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql\*
```

you can delete anything related to packages named mysql.
Those commands are only valid on debian / debian-based linux distributions (Ubuntu for example).

You can list all installed mysql packages with the command:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep -i mysql
```

For more cleanup of the package cache, you can use the command:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Also, remember to use the command:

```
sudo updatedb
```

Otherwise the "locate" command will display old data.

To install mysql again, use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev mysql-client
```

This will install the mysql client, libmysql and its headers files.

To install the mysql server, use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked I guess. Now I want to install mysql in /usr/bin/mysql
I need it's header files and library files in /usr/include/mysql and /usr/lib/mysql respectively. Can you suggestion what Can I do?

Comment: @codeartist Just download the appropriate packets for your distri. It is the cleanest way to go...

Comment: @codeartist : If this answer fix your problem, accept it.Then create new question.Also take a look at unix.stackexchange.com which is for linux/unix questions,  SO is for development related questions.

Comment: @glglgl: I am not able to get library files of mysql in /usr/lib while trying to download it through repository.
Can you tell me what I should do!
My system configuration:

OS: ubuntu 12.04 (gnome 3)

Comment: @rkosegi: I am looking at unix.stackexchange.com. I will try to update such things from there onwards next time.

Comment: answer modified to install mysql, libmysql, libmysqlclient-dev and mysql-server

Comment: But this doesn't remove mysql.user table. How to remove everything and start new root account?

Comment: I still get " root@Debian-76-wheezy-64-LAMP ~ # mysql
Warning: Using unique option prefix pass instead of password is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Any idea how to fix please ?

Comment: @moderns To remove all the existing users and data, you have to remove the Mysql data directories after you have removed mysqld. You can find the data directories in /var/lib/mysql. The next time you install mysql you will start with a fresh install with no legacy data.

Comment: Complete official guide to (un)install at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/

Comment: tried the mentioned steps still for the command :      sudo dpkg -l | grep -i mysql
it lists the mysql packages. The output is same as mentioned by user @Bakepi

Answer (score 17):

Just a little addition to the answer of @dAm2k :

In addition to `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql\*`

I've done a `sudo apt-get remove --purge mariadb\*`.

I seems that in the new release of debian (stretch), when you install mysql it install mariadb package with it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your solution worked for me, while the accepted answer did not, in my case.  Had recently installed LAMP on Raspbian Sketch Lite and it came with MariaDB and since it was still running, the accepted answer solution did not get rid of it and generated an error, while yours completely uninstalled all the modules and I could reinstall it without any problems.  Thx.

Comment: This needs to be the answer for sure. Do note that the command also asks you to keep or remove all databases.

Answer (score 1):

I read the comment section of one of the other answers and it is providing incorrect information. The Data Directory will be different if you are using Debian Package Manager vs HomeBrew (on Debian).

One of my colleagues had issues starting a rails application on his machine. And it seems that the CyberSecurity team ran a security update that corrupted his data directory. These are the steps I followed to help him successfully get his rails app running on his machine:

1. Make yourself admin (if you are using a company computer, you may need to temporarily promote your user with sudo privileges using Self-Service
2. Uninstall Mysql:

   brew uninstall mysql
3. Delete the mysql folders shown, ESPECIALLY the data directory shown.

   ps -ax | grep mysql
4. Confirm data directory:

   file /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
5. Backup your databases:

   cd /opt/homebrew/var/mysql (this is the data directory)

   cp -a database1 ~/Downloads

   cp -a database2 ~/Downloads
6. Now delete the data directory:

   sudo cd ~ && rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
7. Confirm its gone:

   file /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
8. Check if there are any mysql pids still running (even after running brew uninstall mysql). There may be. Terminate those pids:

   ps -ax | grep mysql

   kill -9 [pid]
9. The following command shows you mysql is not installed:

   brew info mysql
10. Install MySQL:

    cd ~ && brew install mysql
11. Now you will be able to log into root with mysql:

    mysql -u root
12. Ruby specific stuff:

    gem list | grep mysql2
13. Ruby specific stuff:

    gem uninstall mysql2 && bundle install
14. Ruby specific stuff:

    rails db:drop

    rails db:create

    rails db:migrate

    rails console