# Login ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql

I just installed MySQL server on my Ubuntu machine. All installed ok, when it asked for my password, I simply hit 'enter' so as to leave the password blank. Now when I try to login:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and simply hit enter, I get the following error:

> ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

I don't understand what the error is or how to fix it. Please can someone help? I've tried to read the MYSQL Docs but I don't understand what they're saying.

I also get an "Access Denied" page when I try to access phpMyAdmin

Comment: See at [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/777008)

Comment: maybe this is helpofull for you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost/64238417#64238417

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue. Executing with Super user privileges worked for me.

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to ommit -p for password free login?

```
mysql -u root
```

Comment: Yeah, I get the same response back, so assuming there is something more fundamentally wrong than a password issue

Comment: Well you could reset the password, but thats a tedious process. Would advice to reinstall and actually SET a password, even if its just 123.

Comment: I tried uninstalling it by doing sudo apt-get purge mysql-server and reinstalled it, but when I reinstalled it, it didn't ask me to put in the password

Comment: try these steps for a clean deinstall: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861374/how-to-remove-mysql-completely-with-config-and-library-files

Comment: Just tried those, reinstalled and still the same thing. Didn't as me to re-enter y password