# /usr/sbin/mysql code=exited status 203/EXEC ERROR

Tags: mysql, systemctl

I don't know exactly what I did wrong, but it's likely some 'chown' operation that I did. I was trying to allow the user&group mysql:mysql access to a /media/usb drive, but may have inadvertently changed something else.

When I do `sudo systemctl start mysql.service` I get an error. Upon examining with `sudo systemctl status mysqld`, I get the following:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-06-19 08:11:01 EDT; 19s ago
  Process: 15459 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
  Process: 15444 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 15459 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC);         : 15460 (mysql-systemd-s)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 2.4M
      CPU: 175ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─15460 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─15687 sleep 1

Jun 19 08:11:01 apil-dlrig systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jun 19 08:11:01 apil-dlrig systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
```

When I check ownership on `/var/lib/mysql`, I get the following, which seems reasonable. I.e. user `mysql` has full ownership on this folder.

```
apil@apil-dlrig:~$ sudo ls -la /var/lib/mysql
total 176212
drwx------  7 mysql mysql     4096 Jun 19 07:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 79 root  root      4096 Oct 30  2019 ..
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql       56 Oct 20  2019 auto.cnf
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql     1680 Nov 22  2019 ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql     1112 Nov 22  2019 ca.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql     1112 Nov 22  2019 client-cert.pem
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql     1676 Nov 22  2019 client-key.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql        0 May  5 06:38 debian-5.7.flag
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql     4096 Jun  6 13:44 foo
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql      665 Jun 19 07:34 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 79691776 Jun 19 07:34 ibdata1
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 50331648 Jun 19 07:34 ib_logfile0
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 50331648 Oct 20  2019 ib_logfile1
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql      155 Jun 16 07:23 keyring_backup
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql     4096 May  5 06:38 mysql
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql        6 May  5 06:38 mysql_upgrade_info
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql     4096 May  5 06:38 performance_schema
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql     1680 Nov 22  2019 private_key.pem
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql     4096 Jun 16 07:25 prod
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql      452 Nov 22  2019 public_key.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql     1112 Nov 22  2019 server-cert.pem
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql     1680 Nov 22  2019 server-key.pem
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql    12288 Nov 22  2019 sys
```

The `/etc/systemd/system/multi.user.wants.targets/mysql.service` looks as the following. Nothing should've changed here, i.e. it is as default as MySQL comes.

```
# MySQL systemd service file

[Unit]
Description=MySQL Community Server
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=mysql
Group=mysql
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld
ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
TimeoutSec=600
Restart=on-failure
RuntimeDirectory=mysqld
RuntimeDirectoryMode=755
```

Wondering what could be going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the original error, the issue is: `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)`. Looks like some kind of execution privilege for the `mysqld` file? Checked it too:

`ls -la /usr/sbin/mysqld` which returned

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24585896 Apr 30 10:52 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

So the issue (I thought) was that user root didn't have the execute permission. Looks at the first three letters `rw-`. The last dash means no execution privilege.

So I simply ran the following `chmod 777 /usr/sbin/mysqld`, after which the ownership returns as

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24585896 Apr 30 10:52 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Now, `systemctl start mysql.service` runs just fine.

It's amazing how simply the process of writing a question on stackoverflow actually helps me solve a problem 80% of the time. Thanks again, folks.

Comment: `chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=-` would be better - you do not want to have write-rights for world to /usr/sbin/mysqld